# VSCode Python - Automatically Implementing Abstract Methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any support to automatically implement all abstract methods of an abstract class in VSCode with Python Environment?

```
class AbstractClass(ABC):

    @abstractclass
    def abstract_method():
        pass

class NonAbstractClass(AbstractClass):

    # shortcut in vscode to implement all abstract methods
    # it works if I start writing methods and then it autocompletes, that is not what I am looking for
```

Comment: It seems impossible for now. I have creat a feature request, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17121)

Comment: Thanks, I hope they release something soon.